# How to access repeater textbox in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, repeater, webmethod

I'm making a RealTime Comment System in Asp.net Webforms ajax jquery....
I have a Repeater where i have one TextBox and one Button ... i want simply insertion through ajax jquery but jquery ajax didn't find out TextBox which is declared inside Repeater control...

***Script:***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnComment').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.aspx/insertComment",
                data: '{comtext: "' +txtComment.value + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("ok");
                    //$('#txtComment').val("");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

when i debug the script i the problem with data....txtComment.value...
but when i try for TextBox outside the Repeater like this:
data: '{comtext: "' + $("#<%=txtComment.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }'
then it works for me but not findout TextBox inside Repeater

***Code Behind:***

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string insertComment(string comtext)
    {

        //Button btnComment = sender as Button;
        //RepeaterItem item = btnComment.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
        //TextBox txtComment = item.FindControl("txtComment") as TextBox;
        //lblMsg.Text = txtComment.Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=RIO;initial catalog=SocialNetworkSite;integrated security=true");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Comment (comtext) values ('" + comtext + "')", con);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        return comtext;
    }
```

please HELP

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Your WebMethod can't and shouldn't access controls from the page. In order to answer why your jQuery can't find `#txtComment` you'd need to show how you created it. Most likely is that the ID on the client side doesn't match what you expect.

Comment: this is the TextBox which i want to access in the script but can't...

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtComment" CssClass="txtComment" placeholder="write a comment..."></asp:TextBox>

and i don't know very well about jquery but i think it could be done using traversing.....

i tried this...
var textBoxValue = $(this).closest("div").find("#txtComment").val();

data: '{comtext: "' + textBoxValue + '"}'

but it shows .....textBoxValue=undefined........

please help me

Comment: Like I said, look at your ID of your text box on the client side. What yuou sert in the ASPX markup isn't necessarily what you get in the resulting page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $("#MyRepeater").on("click", ".MyButton", function() {
   var textBoxValue = $(this).closest("tr").find(".MyTextBox").val(); //$("#MyTextBox").val();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "index.aspx/insertComment",
     data: '{comtext: "' + textBoxValue + '"}',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
       alert("ok");
       //$('#txtComment').val("");
     }
   });
 })
```

```
[WebMethod]
public static string insertComment(string MyTextboxValue)
{

   // Button btnComment = sender as Button;
   // RepeaterItem item = btnComment.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
   // TextBox txtComment = item.FindControl("txtComment") as TextBox;
    //lblMsg.Text = txtComment.Text;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=RIO;initial catalog=SocialNetworkSite;integrated security=true");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Comment (comtext) values ('" + MyTextboxValue + "')", con);
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return "Success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return ex.Message;
    }
    finally {
        con.Close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: $("#repeater1").on("click", "#btnComment", function() {.......its not working for me instead i use $('#btnComment').click(function () {....... but now textBoxValue assigned "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

this line works for me..

```
var textBoxValue = $(this).parent("div").siblings('div').children('.txtComment').val();
```